# Why the hIndex is 3 and not 0, since there are 5 papers with 0 citations?

Tags: algorithm

In academia, the h-index is a metric used to calculate the impact of a researcher's papers. It is calculated as follows:

A researcher has index h if at least h of her N papers have h citations each. If there are multiple h satisfying this formula, the maximum is chosen.

```
Input: citations = [0,1,3,5,6]
Output: 3 
Explanation: [0,1,3,5,6] means the researcher has 5 papers in total and each of them had 
             received 0, 1, 3, 5, 6 citations respectively. 
             Since the researcher has 3 papers with at least 3 citations each and the remaining 
             two with no more than 3 citations each, her h-index is 3.

0 # there is 1 paper with citation 0
1 # there are 4 papers have citations at least 1
3 # there are 3 papers have citations at least 3
5 # there are 2 papers have citations at least 5
6 # there are 1 paper have citations at least 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recheck the definition (pay attention to `h`):

> A researcher has index **h** if at least **h** of her N papers have **h** citations each (at least)

So, the number of papers that have the score, should be equal to the score! The only number of papers that is equal to the score, is 3. Other cases, such as "5 papers with 0 score" does not satisfy the definition.

Comment: What will be the h index for "citations = [10,20,30,40,50]"?

Comment: @user754657 `5`.

Comment: @user754657: you just sort in descending order. If the value at index *i* is at least *i*, you continue counting, until you reach the element where that does not hold. The number of items where this was true, is the h-index.